# How to install Perl modules on Debian 9?

Tags: debian, perl

On a tutorial for installing `SendEmail`, I found instructions to install 2 prequisites, 2 perl modules

```
apt-get install 'perl(Net::SSLeay)' 'perl(IO::Socket::SSL)'
```

This syntax also resulted strange to my Debian 9

> E: Unable to find package perl(Net::SSLeay)
>
> E: Unable to find package perl(IO::Socket::SSL)

I tried using `cpan`, (I honestly do not know what is ... ) but it ended In some syntax errors

**EDIT, more doubts**

In this ['Ask Ubuntu' question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604346/unable-to-locate-package-perlnet-iosocket), I see instructions to executed

```
apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

But in the tutorial I am following, instructions is to execute *first*

```
apt-get install libnet-ssleay-perl libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

and *then*

```
apt-get install 'perl(Net::SSLeay)' 'perl(IO::Socket::SSL)'
```

Comment: "_On a tutorial for installing `SendEmail`..._" what tutorial?

Comment: I didn't linked it because it's in our intranet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to install Perl modules on Debian 9?

1) through `cpan`:

```
cpan Module::Name
```

eg:

```
cpan IO::Socket::SSL
cpan Net::SSLeay
```

2) Through `apt`

Use `apt-file` to get the exact package name then install it. To install `apt-file`:

```
apt install apt-file
apt-file update
```

To get the package name:

```
apt-file search Module/Name
```

or :

```
apt-file search Module/Name | awk '{print $1}' | uniq |  tr -d \:
```

e,g:

```
apt-file search IO/Socket/SSL | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | tr -d \:
```

sample output:

```
libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

Installing `libio-socket-ssl-perl` package will install the `IO::Socket::SSL` perl module:

```
apt install libio-socket-ssl-perl
```

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer but it's not a direct answer to my question.

Actually I was installing sendemail, and I discovered just now that debian 9 has an officiale package, so I do not answered my question, but resolved my problem simply doing

```
apt install sendemail
```

I'll leave open this question for a while because I think the question was interesting

Comment: The 2 perl modules will be installed as suggests dependencies. [sendemail package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/sendemail)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I do

```
apt search <package> | grep perl
```

Note, that package name is lowercase. In your case it is `apt search ssleay | grep perl`